# Estou querendo fazer com que esse meu codigo fique retornando em Tempo Real

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

Estou com um comando de economia e queria que quando o usuario, que já usou o comando, espere 30minutos mas que o codigo retorne um erro informando tempo restante para usar o comando novamente como faço ?

```
-- CODIGO
const cooldown = new Set();
const db = require('quick.db');
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(','))return;  

    const user = message.author;
    const author = await db.fetch(`work_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)

    const timeout = 1800000;

    if (author !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - message.author) > 0) {
        const time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - message.author));
    
        if (cooldown.has(message.author.id)){
        message.channel.send(` ${user} | <a:negado:872682572965118033> Você já trabalhou hoje,Tente denovo em **${timeout} minutos**`)
      } else {

        const replies = ['Programador','Construtor','Bancário','Motorista','Chefe','Mecanico']

        const result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length));
        const amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        message.channel.send(` ${user} | <a:azul:876222068688052315> Você trabalhou como **${replies[result]}** e Ganhou Salario De **${amount}** `)
        
        db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
        db.set(`work_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())
        cooldown.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
            cooldown.delete(message.author.id)
        }, `${timeout}`);
    };
}
}
```

Comment: não entendi @Danizavtz

Comment: Ah sim, alguem já editou a pergunta, agora já está com aparência correta.

Comment: Consegue Me Ajudar @Danizavtz

Comment: Não consigo, não entendo nada dessas libs que está usando.

Comment: é para uma aplicação de bot dentro do discord @Danizavtz

Comment: `const time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - message.author));` isso aqui já está confuso, `message.author` seria um número. Mas enfim, o que eu faria seria usar um `Map` no lugar do `Set` associando o id do usuário e um timestamp de espera, faria a busca por id, verificaria o timestamp atual com o de limite do usuário e retornaria uma mensagem com diferenca de tempo caso fosse valor positivo.

Comment: @CmteCardeal Sugere Só Alterar o "Set" Para "Map"